# How to configure buf.yaml to search for external dependency protos>

Tags: google-cloud-platform, proto, protocol-buffers

I am trying to run buf lint. One of my proto uses external proto "google/type/money.proto" which is [here](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/type/money.proto)

I am struggling to get this proto available for the buf lint to run. I have searched and gone through the documentation but have not understood much.

I even have updated from buf 0.20 to 0.38 which provides us the facility to include dependency.

Please help!!

Comment: Which GCP product are you using?

Answer (score 1):

you can add dependency in your buf.yaml to buf.build/googleapis/googleapis which has the proto you mentioned.

```
version: v1
deps:
  - buf.build/googleapis/googleapis
```